# Error during in-memory compilation and loading of classes with annotation processing

Tags: java, annotation-processing, java-compiler-api

I am compiling and loading classes in memory with `JavaCompiler`.

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask compile = compiler.getTask(null, inMemoryFileManager, diagnostics, null, annotationClasses, compilationUnits);
if (!compile.call()) {
   diagnostics.getDiagnostics().forEach(System.err::println);
}
```

I am using a similar `Filemanager` and `SimpleJavaObject` as in [this example](http://normalengineering.com.au/normality/c-and-java-code-snippets/java-runtime-compilation-in-memory/). I modified it slightly to be able to handle multiple files. If you need my source code please let me know.

The code above runs fine as long as `annotationClasses` is null.
When I try to add classes to annotation processing however I get the following error:

```
Class names, '<classNames>', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
```

For *classNames* I tried **Main**, **Main.java**, **package.Main** and **package.Main.java**. They all result in the same error.

I know this is a very specific scenario. Did anybody try to do something similar and can help me?

**Edit**:

```
    /* Container for a Java compilation unit (ie Java source) in memory. */
    private static class CompilationUnit extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
        private final String source;

        public CompilationUnit(String className, String source) {
            super(URI.create("file:///" + className.replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".java"), Kind.SOURCE);
            this.source = source;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
            return source;
        }

        @Override
        public OutputStream openOutputStream() {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream openInputStream() {
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(source.getBytes());
        }
    }

    /* Container for Java byte code in memory. */
    private static class ByteJavaFileObject extends SimpleJavaFileObject {
        private ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;

        public ByteJavaFileObject(String className) {
            super(URI.create("byte:///" + className.replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".class"), Kind.CLASS);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getCharContent(boolean ignoreEncodingErrors) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public OutputStream openOutputStream() {
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            return byteArrayOutputStream;
        }

        @Override
        public InputStream openInputStream() {
            return null;
        }

        public byte[] getByteCode() {
            return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        }
    }

    private static class InMemoryFileManager extends ForwardingJavaFileManager {
        private final InMemoryClassLoader inMemoryClassLoader;

        public InMemoryFileManager(JavaCompiler compiler, Map<String, ByteJavaFileObject> fileObjects) {
            super(compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null));
            inMemoryClassLoader = new InMemoryClassLoader(fileObjects);
        }

        @Override
        public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(Location notUsed, String className, JavaFileObject.Kind kind, FileObject sibling) throws IOException {
            return inMemoryClassLoader.getFileObject(className);
        }

        @Override
        public ClassLoader getClassLoader(Location location) {
            return inMemoryClassLoader;
        }

        public InMemoryClassLoader getClassLoader() {
            return inMemoryClassLoader;
        }
    }

    private static class InMemoryClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
        private final Map<String, ByteJavaFileObject> fileObjects;

        public InMemoryClassLoader(Map<String, ByteJavaFileObject> fileObjects) {
            this.fileObjects = fileObjects;
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> findClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            ByteJavaFileObject fileObject = fileObjects.get(className);
            return defineClass(className, fileObject.getByteCode(), 0, fileObject.getByteCode().length);
        }

        JavaFileObject getFileObject(String className) {
            return fileObjects.get(className);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried package/Main.java?

Comment: Yes it gives not a valid class name.

Comment: Alright. What are you trying to accomplish? If you can share some source code, that would be helpful.

Comment: Well I am trying to compile and load jpa classes with annotation processing. It would be nice if I can accomplish this in memory. I will edit my question to show the source code.

Comment: Makes sense. What are you trying to accomplish by setting annotationClasses to something other than null? I ask only because in the several times that I've used this api I don't believe that I've ever passed anything inn for that parameter.

Comment: I just read the javadoc again and I think you are right I should set it to null.  Ah then the problem lies with JPA. I got the jpa error **bean class not found, does it have @Entity annotation**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81867/discussion-between-eclipse-and-jbunting).